# How to connect an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to a SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am novice user of ASP.NET MVC application. I am trying to learn mvc but I am unable to connect database to my application. Whenever I am going to add controller with model it shows error shown in image[image]

My server name is `winultimate-PC` and database name is `content`

So please help me how can I connect this application with SQL Server.

I am also attaching model class to which I want to attach my database

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you using the SQL Server **Express** version that was installed with Visual Studio? Or are you using a separate, full version of SQL Server?

Comment: For SQL Server connection strings - see [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) with tons of examples and explanations

Comment: I am using seperate sql server 2008 using sql server management studio

Comment: Then you should **definitely** not use `.\SQLEXPRESS` as your server name! Use `.` (or `(local)` or the machine name) for the local default instance of SQL Server

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WelderDB"
       connectionString="data source=WINULTIMATE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=content;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings> I used this connection string but still not working so please correct connection string so I Can able to connect to SQL server

Comment: But see: you're **again** using the `SQLEXPRESS` instance! That's **NOT** your *full* SQL Server version - that's the **Express** version that's installed alongside Visual Studio. Use `data source=WINULTIMATE-PC` alone - no `\SQLEXPRESS` appended to it. Use: `connectionString="data source=WINULTIMATE-PC;Initial Catalog=content;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" `

Comment: I also did the same what u told me now but still generate error shown in image

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides details about how to connect MS SQL SERVER 2008 database to asp.net MVC Application

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_database.asp

Comment: W3Schools is a **bad** site - [see here: W3Fools why](http://w3fools.com/) - I would **avoid** it and definitely not recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the `[Key]` annotation in you Welder entity.

```
[Key]
public int ID 
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

You also need to add the following `using` statement:

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Comment: This is secondary thing first how can I connect with server 2008 whenever trying add controller with welder model it gives error shown in image and i also tried what u have told me

Comment: There could be several issues with your connection string. Is the SQLEXPRESS instance on the local machine? Can you definitely use integrated security?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with managment studio and in web.config i used this connection string <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WelderDB"
       connectionString="data source=WINULTIMATE-PC;Initial Catalog=content;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings> but still gives an error.

Comment: In that particular case your source doesn't have an instance specified like this: `source=WINULTIMATE-PC\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: We seem to have established that he is not using the SQLEXPRESS instance, he is using the default instance (which does not have an instance name)